# How to get all comments from Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get **ALL** comments (and the replies to those comments) from a Facebook page and an specific date range on API Graph.

Not just the comments from `me/posts` or `me/feed`, but all the comments my Fanpage gets, including those from Events, Products, Photos (because if you post a collection of photos the `me/posts` edge just include the main posts, not every single photo attached in the post), Videos, Live Videos, Offers, and, if its possible, Dark Posts (from Facebook Ads).

Is there a way to make this? I tried using `me/notifications` edge but most of the notifications group several comments together in a single object (E.g. "Bob, John and Mary commented on the link you shared.").

By the way, there is actually and app that makes this, called "Feed Comments" (id=9675640871), actually the responsible to send the notifications when your fanpage gets a comment.

But I don't know how it makes it.

Thanks!

Comment: did you read about webhooks in the docs?

Comment: Yes, but that's for real time, and I want to do the requests on demand